# SQL update with count gets only nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and SSRS 2008 to generate the report.  I am trying to update a table to get a count of the results from another table.

```
UPDATE r
SET r.Race = d2.Race,
    r.RaceNum = d2.count
FROM @results r
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT d.Race,
          COUNT(d.race) AS 'count'
   FROM #Demographic d
   GROUP BY d.Race)d2 ON r.Race = d2.Race
```

An insert works perfectly but I am inserting several times into the results table to create a demographics report.  This is creating a lot Null data at the table of the results.  If anyone has an idea of what I am going wrong the help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are referring to an insert in your question, but your code shows no insert statement. Do you also have additional code for the insert?

Answer (score 0):

Not certain, but first guess is that count is a reserved word... change it to something else such as...

```
update r 
set r.Race = d2.Race, r.RaceNum = d2.cnt 
from @results r
inner join
(select d.Race, COUNT(d.race) as 'cnt' from #Demographic d group by d.Race)d2
on r.Race = d2.Race
```

or alternatively try delimiting the column identifier as `[count]` or if you have quoted identifiers on `"count"`

Answer (score 0):

Your query is:

```
update r 
    set r.Race = d2.Race,                              /*<---------*/
        r.RaceNum = d2.count 
    from @results r inner join
         (select d.Race, COUNT(d.race) as 'count'
          from #Demographic d
          group by d.Race
         ) d2
         on r.Race = d2.Race                            /*<-------- */
```

The two marked lines stand out.  You are joining on values using `=`, then you are setting one equal to the other.  This may not be the problem, but it is suspicious.  If you are joining on them, why are you setting them equal?  My suspicion is that the join is failing, because nothing matches it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to update the race column, since that's the equality portion of your join.

As written, any race not in #demographic would have its racenum set to null.  If you want 0 for those try:

```
UDPATE 
    r 
SET 
    r.RaceNum = ISNULL(d2.ct, 0)
FROM @results r
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            d.Race
            , COUNT(d.race) as ct 
        FROM 
            #Demographic d 
        GROUP BY 
            d.Race
    ) d2
ON 
    r.Race = d2.Race
```